# What difference between the Queryable.Contains method and the List<T>.Contains method in C#?

Tags: c#

```
List<A> list=new List<A>();
var a=new A();
list.Add(a);
list.Contains(a);
list.Contains<A>(a);
```

What difference between this two cases?
Why exists two method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in this case between List.Contains (which is the implementation of ICollection.Contains) and Enumerable.Contains - in the case where the enumerable is a collection, IEnumerable.Contains simply invokes ICollection.Contains.

The reasoning there is that some collections - such as SortedSet - can implement a Contains method that operates at better than O(n) time.  For non-collection types of Enumerable, IEnumerable.Contains will do a linear search over the enumeration.

There is also Queryable.Contains, but that's different - List isn't a queryable.  Queryable.Contains can build this into a query expression which can be translated (for example, into SQL).  Queryable and Enumerable extension methods are very different under the hood.

Comment: Queryable.Contains is implement by a HashSet ?

Comment: Queryable.Contains is implemented by query providers, which typically are classes that build query trees to translate C# queries into other types of queries, such as SQL.  One example would be the DbSet or ObjectSet classes from the Entity Framework.  Traditional collections like HashSet and List are Enumerable but not queryable; Queryable collections are really used for external data sources like databases, while C# object collections in memory tend to just be Enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask about difference in its functionality, then there is actually none.

`List.Contains()` is a part of `ICollection` interface and exists since .NET Framework 2.0. Developers have always used this method before LINQ to check if `List` or another `ICollection` contains an item.

`.Contains<T>` is a part of LINQ. It is a query language which allows you to use this method with all `IEnumerable` collections, even arrays or custom; data sources likes databases; data formats like JSON or XML etc.

Actually, when you call LINQ `.Contains<T>` on `IEnumerable` collection which is `ICollection` (for example, `List<T>`), it does call its own `ICollection.Contains` method.

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value)
{
  ICollection<TSource> collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
  if (collection != null)
    return collection.Contains(value);
  return Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(source, value, (IEqualityComparer<TSource>) null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithmic complexity of "LIST.contains" is O(n) always.

Where as "Queryable.contains" complexity depends on the collection implemented. For example, if underlying collection is "Hashset", then the algorithmic complexity is O(1).