# How do I convert this looped code to a single LINQ implementation?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to optimise the code below which loops through objects one by one and does a database lookup. I want to make a LINQ statement that will do the same task in one transaction.

This is my inefficient looped code;

```
IStoreUnitOfWork uow = StoreRepository.UnitOfWorkSource.GetUnitOfWorkFactory().CreateUnitOfWork(); 
var localRunners = new List<Runners>();
foreach(var remoteRunner in m.Runners) {                                                           
    var localRunner = uow.CacheMarketRunners.Where(x => x.SelectionId == remoteRunner.SelectionId && x.MarketId == m.MarketId).FirstOrDefault();  
    localRunners.Add(localRunner);
}
```

This is my very feable attempt at a single query to do the same thing. Well it's not even an attempt. I don't know where to start. The remoteRunners object has a composite key.

```
IStoreUnitOfWork uow = StoreRepository.UnitOfWorkSource.GetUnitOfWorkFactory().CreateUnitOfWork(); 
var localRunners = new List<Runners>();
var localRunners = uow.CacheMarketRunners.Where(x =>
   x.SelectionId in remoteRunners.SelectionId &&
   x.MarketId    in remoteRunners.MarketId);
```

Thank you for looking

Comment: List<Runners> localRunners = uow.CacheMarketRunners.Where(x => x.SelectionId == remoteRunner.SelectionId && x.MarketId == m.MarketId).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

Comment: You'll have to actually build up an expression that or's those conditions together like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49236110/302918)

Comment: Alternatively you can create a list of string representations of the 2 values like `var remotes = m.Runners.Select(r => r.SelectionId + ";" + r.MarketId).ToList()` then use it like `Where(x => remotes.Contains(x.SelectionId + ";" + x.MarketId))`.  Note however that this will not be as efficient of a query as it cannot take advantage of any indexes on those columns.

Comment: @jdweng That makes no sense.

Comment: @juharr Thank you. I think I can get it working that way. Seems like a painful thing to have to do tho! I shall try it.

Comment: @Obbles Nevermind I see now that there is just one `MarketId`, so you can just have a check against that and then a `Contains` on all the `SelectionId`s like Harald's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have an object `m`, which has a property `MarketId`. Object `m` also has a sequence of `Runners`, where every `Runner` has a property `SelectionId`.

Your database has `CacheMarketRunners`. Every `CacheMarketRunner` has a `MarketId` and a `SelectionId`.

Your query should return all`CacheMarketRunners` with a `MarketId` equal to `m.MarketId` and a `SelectionId` that is contained in the sequence `m.Runners.SelectionId`.

If your `m` does not have too many `Runners`, say less then 250, consider using [Queryable.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338641%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var requestedSelectionIds = m.Runners.Select(runner => runner.SelectionId);
var result = CacheMarketRunners.Where(cacheMarketRunner =>
     cacheMarketRunner.MarketId == m.MarketId
     && requestedSelectionIds.Contains(cacheMarketRunner.SelectionId));
```

Comment: Very succinct explanation thank you. In terms of Queryable.Contains. I needed to understand why, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969964/what-difference-between-the-queryable-contains-method-and-the-listt-contains-m explains why.

Comment: There is an assumption under this answer: Every item in `m.Runner` has only one matching `CacheMarketRunner` with equal `SelectionId`. Originally, the number of results must equal to `m.Runner.Count()` because of the for loop, but now if more than one `CacheMarketRunner` has the same `SelectionId` with items in `m.Runner`, more results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance, you need caching transaction results:

```
var marketRunners = uow.CacheMarketRunners.Where(x => x.MarketId == m.MarketId).ToList();
```

Transaction results regarding `uow` are stored in the `List`, such that you don't have transaction in the for loop. Hence performance should be improved:

```
var localRunners = new List<Runners>();
foreach(var remoteRunner in m.Runners) {                                                           
    var localRunner = marketRunners.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SelectionId == remoteRunner.SelectionId);
    localRunners.Add(localRunner);
}
```

You can even remove the for loop:

```
var localRunners = m.Runners.Select(remoteRunner => marketRunners.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SelectionId == remoteRunner.SelectionId)).ToList();
```

Comment: It really depends on the data in the database.  That first query might return a lot more data than needed.  It's best to do as much filtering on the DB side as possible.